# How to update Pentaho Spoon JDBC drivers

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, pentaho

I'm trying to connect to a postgresql 13 DB hosted on my computer using spoon.

I get the following error when trying to connect

```
Error connecting to database [DW] :org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occurred while trying to connect to the database

Error connecting to database: (using class org.postgresql.Driver)
The authentication type 10 is not supported. Check that you have configured the pg_hba.conf file to include the client's IP address or subnet, and that it is using an authentication scheme supported by the driver.


org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occurred while trying to connect to the database

Error connecting to database: (using class org.postgresql.Driver)
The authentication type 10 is not supported. Check that you have configured the pg_hba.conf file to include the client's IP address or subnet, and that it is using an authentication scheme supported by the driver.
```

I did some digging and that's due to an outdated JDBC driver. Can anyone help me update the driver? I have located the driver directory but the guide on the website https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/5.4/0D0/160/030
is just crap, they require you to have a distribute-files.bat file? Which I couldn't find anywhere.

Comment: The instructions look straight forward to me.  What OS are you using? If it is not Windows then you will not find `distribute-files.bat`, instead you need to look for `distribute-drivers.sh`. In either case they should be in `~pentaho/jdbc-distribution`.

Comment: These files aren't there though! The instructions are 4 years old

Comment: So what version of Pentaho are you on?

Comment: Already fixed it! It turns out you don't have to follow the distribute-files.bat steps. Just pasting the JDBC driver is enough. They should really update their userguides if they want pentaho to be a bit more mainstream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to follow all the steps. Just pasting the JAR file in the directory is enough.